# How can I have a child element manipulate parents sibling?

Tags: jquery

This is what my data looks like:

```
<div class="shower">
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="hider">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="shower">
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="hider">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Onclick of hider I want to hide() .container and show .shower that's located before closest .container. Onclick of .shower I want to hide .shower that was clicked and show next .container.

How would I achieve this in jquery? Should I restructure my html?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$('.hider').click(function(e) {
  var container = $(this).parent().parent();
  container.hide();
  var shower = container.prev();
  shower.show();
})
```

jsFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/eqDWk/

Or this if you want to use [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$('.hider').click(function(e) {
  var container = $(this).closest('.container');
  container.hide();
  var shower = container.prev();
  shower.show();
})
```

jsFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/eqDWk/1/

Answer (score 2):

Based on [icyrock's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438544/icyrock-com) nice code, you would add this to show the container again:

```
$('.hider').click(function(e) {
  var container = $(this).parent().parent();
  container.hide();
  var shower = container.prev();
  shower.show();
})

$('.shower').click(function(e) {
  var container = $(this).next();
  container.show();
  $(this).hide();
})
​
```

jsFiddle fork of icyrock's original: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7ZTN/1/